# What is wrong in the DFS traversal of this Graph (using recursive approach)?

Tags: recursion, graph, depth-first-search

Can someone please help me clarify my understanding of DFS using recursive approach?[image]

In the above Undirected graph, if I perform DFS using recursive approach the output varies depending on when the vertex neighbors are added.

i.e. for Vertex 0, if neighbors are added in sequence of Vertex 8, 3 & 1. Then the result is => 0 8 4 3 2 5 6 7 1

The issue with this result is that there is no connection between 6 & 7. In this case is this result valid?

But for Vertex 0, if neighbors are added in sequence of Vertex 1, 3 & 8. Then the result is => 0 1 7 2 3 4 8 5 6          which makes sense.

If my understanding is right, how can we write a stable DFS using recursion.

Here is my code that I wrote after going through your explanation.

```
void dfsRecursion(Vertex startV){
        startV.setVisited(true);
        System.out.print(startV);
        for(Vertex v: startV.getNeighbors()){
            if (!v.isVisited()){
                dfsRecursion(v);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume "result" means the the order of vertex transversal and not a "path".

Comment: That's right. I mean the order of vertex. I think now I have some idea. I think that order is because of backtracking. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think so too.